# Print file names if they don't match a pattern

Tags: shell, awk, sed

I have lots of text files containing lists of numbers, buried inside lots of folders. Most files/lists are identical, I'm looking for a way to find those who aren't.

The lists should contain these numbers exactly:

```
0
50
100
150
200
250
300
350
```

I'm looking for a way to print to a text file, the file names and paths of files who aren't exactly like this.

I tried using awk, sed and other shell tools but as I'm very new to this I failed miserably. I was hoping to get an example with some explanations.

Thanks!

Comment: What is exactly like this ? From 0 to 350 with step 50 on 8 lines ?

Comment: Yup. All (most) files contain exactly the same list but have different file names themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RefFile=./ThisFile

find . -type f -exec cksum {} \; \
 | awk -v "Ref=$( cksum ${RefFile} )" '
     BEGIN { split( Ref, aRef); crc=aRef[1] }
     $1 != crc { print $3}
     '
```

Will return file that are not the same as the referenced file

Answer (score 1):

If the files should be exact duplicates, you know two things: their size should be 29 bytes and their md5sum should be `00c7dd845c7e87a1d1751566bd23ad61` - because

```
seq 0 50 350 | wc -c
seq 0 50 350 | md5sum
```

So, just search for files of different size or different md5sum:

```
find . -not -size 29c
find . -size 29c -exec md5sum {} + \
    | grep -v ^00c7dd845c7e87a1d1751566bd23ad61 \
    | cut -f2 -d\*
```

Comment: 2 questions: The file names differ from one another. Doesn't that affect the md5? Also, how would i print all the non-matching file names and paths to a single text file?

Comment: @o_ren: File names are irrelevant for md5. Have you tried running the commands? They already produce the list of non-matching files.

Comment: I just tried to run your command. I can see a list of "bad" files in the terminal. I tried adding >>/path/to/badlist.txt at the end of the command but the badlist.txt file only shows the last file on the list :/

Comment: @o_ren: These are two commands. The first line needs the redirection, too.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '
  # NR is numbers of rows read global
  # FNR is numbers of rows read for each file 
  # NR==FNR is only true for the first file
  # store the lines from the first file in an array 
  # use next to skip the next condition
  NR==FNR { a[NR]=$0; next }
  # this part is only ran when NR!=FNR
  # check to see if the array value is equal the row we currently read:
  a[FNR]!=$0 { print FILENAME }
' checkfile fileA fileB fileC ...
```

This will however print the filename for each time it differs from `checkfile` but this can be solved with: `| uniq`:

```
awk '
  NR==FNR { a[NR]=$0; next }
  a[FNR]!=$0 { print FILENAME }
' checkfile fileA fileB fileC | uniq
```

If line order doesn't matter you can use `$0` as the key for the array:

```
awk '
  NR==FNR { a[$0]=1; next }
  !($0 in a) { print FILENAME }
' checkfile fileA fileB fileC
```